# Mystery error: "Failed to open database phenotype.db, database is locked." Can't find any info online

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I was trying to test an app and it wouldn't launch, instead I kept getting this error:

```
Failed to open database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/phenotype.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
```

I can't find any information about this error online, and no information on what phenotype.db does. I was not doing anything related to databases at the time when I tested this; the only changes I made were layout-related.

Weirdly enough this happened on another app I was testing a few weeks ago. It was a different app, being tested on a different device, from a different computer, and the exact same error came up. In that case I switched to a different device and the error went away. However now the device I switched to is having that error.

Is this some kind of glitch with Google? What can I do to resolve it so I can test my app?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360400/error-code-5-database-is-locked-when-using-a-contentprovider

Comment: Are you using databases in your app, anywhere?

Comment: I am getting the same error since yesterday. Didn't do anything, don't even use SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to close the database, or another thread is writing to the database when you are trying to write to it. `SQLite` locks the database when it is writing to it to avoid corruption if another entity tries to write to the same database at the same time. Android, will only show a error in logcat, and the query you supplied will be just forgotten.
Recommendations:

- You only access the database from one `SQLOpenHelper`
- You make sure you close all instances of database helpers once you have finished with them
- You make sure you always end transactions with `endTransaction()` also if you do not set them successful (i.e. if you want to roll 'em back), in case you use transactions